# character controllers in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have decided to learn Unity and ı started to watch videos in meanwhile on youtube.To create a character ,they need a package and the way importing that package is Assets>>İmport Package>>Character controller.I am doing the same but there is not any package named "character controller".My unity version is 5.1.1f1 and free version.Still working but can't find anything.Do you have any idea how can ı solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can import "unity sample assets" package and go to character and use first/third person character prefab based on your need.

BTW, stackoverflow is only for coding related questions, for other stuff use gamedev.stackexchange.